# Calling a usercontrol from a master page with a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

in the default.master i am calling this user control

```
<uc8:MenuMain2 ID="MenuMain2" runat="server" RootCategoryId="30" ImageHeight="40"
                    ImageWidth="900" />
```

i want to use a variable form my code behind for the value of RootCategoryId, how can i do this, if i am trying to use a variable i am getting "`this is not script let. will output as plain text`"

Answer (score 1):

`MenuMain2` is a `class`. Add a public property to it called `RootCategoryId`. This will allow you to assign values to it from client and server side:

For example, add this to your MenuMain2 control code-behind:

```
public string RootCategoryId {get; set;}
```

Comment: yes im doing this, but how can i then build the <uc8: in the codebehind and pass it to the markup page?

Answer (score 1):

As @Boomer mention you should use Properties, not fields in your class implementation.

Every Control should care his properties in ViewState. This is Microsoft practice [MSDN prooflink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/cpguide/html/cpconmantainingstateincontrol.asp)

It's not enough to use

```
public string RootCategoryId {get; set;}
```

Save your value in ViewState:

```
public string RootCategoryId
{
  get
  {
    return ViewState["RootCategoryId"] == null ?
       "Default Value!" :
       (string)ViewState["RootCategoryId"];
  }
  set { ViewState["RootCategoryId"] = value; }
}
```

In this case value that you assign to this propertie in source code will persist during postbacks.

Another source to read: http://aspnetresources.com/articles/ViewState